# A function/API to list out the supported hyperparameters of SageMaker built-in algorithm

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

I am looking for a function/API that can list out all the hyperparameters supported by the built-in algorithms on SageMaker. I fully understand that the best place to look at this list (manually though) is this link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/algos.html

But I have a requirement in which the Python code should have the capability to fetch all available hyperparameters for an algorithm.

Is there a way to do this?

An added bonus to this would be to also get the supported data-types, Scaling type, Value / Range supported for the respective hyperparameters.

Comment: Even I am looking for the same.Thanks